# how to use assignment operator with classes instead of new () Like wrapper class in java?

Tags: java, class

how to use assignment operator with classes instead of new() Like wrapper class

```
Integer i = 3;

newClass c = 3; // didn't work
```

newClass c = 3; --> didn't work

I know there are overloading operators in c++ which do this, but how to overload assignment operator in java ?!

Comment: That's the assignment operator, not the equality operator.

Comment: you just cant do that in java....

Comment: You can't overload any operators in Java. The only reason it works with `Integer` is because of auto-boxing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's not the "equal operator," it's the assignment operator.
2. No, you can't do that. You must use `new` (or reflection).
3. Java doesn't have operator overloading. (The reason you can do `Integer i = 3;` is because autoboxing of primitives is built into the language, not because the `Integer` class does something with overloading.)

Answer (score 0):

For integers, you can assign as follows:

```
Integer i = 3; //or int i =3;
```

Where as for Class types, you can't do it:

```
newClass c = 3;
```

Rather you can create an object (with new operator) and assign it to a reference variable as follows:

```
Product product = new Product();//example
```

Here, `product` is a reference and and assigning it to a new object (`new Product()`) on the heap.

Comment: So long as you don't assume it was me, please. :-)